# Wildfly-8.2 start up failure with JBAS014674: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.cmp

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8

I am trying to start up wildfly-8.2 standalone , i am getting an exception . Please check exception log below.

```
    C:\jboss\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "C:\jboss\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\jboss\wildfly-8.2.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

===============================================================================

12:53:13,775 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
12:53:14,138 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
12:53:14,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" starting
12:53:14,767 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014
676: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:112) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: JBAS014674: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.cmp
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:325) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:137) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:104) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS013452: Legacy extension 'org.jboss.as.cmp' is not supported on servers running this vers
ion. The extension is only supported for use by hosts running a previous release in a mixed-version managed domain
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS013452: Legacy extension 'org.jboss.as.cmp' is not supported on servers running this version. The extension is only supported for
use by hosts running a previous release in a mixed-version managed domain
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.AbstractLegacyExtension.initializeParsers(AbstractLegacyExtension.java:82) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:183) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124) [wildfly-controller-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]

12:53:15,101 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
12:53:15,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015950: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" stopped in 16ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. Apparently i was using standalone.xml from jboss 7.1.1 which does not work. I replaced it with default standalone.xml which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but it looks like you managed to get the 'org.jboss.as.cmp' extension into the configuration file. Try looking into standalone.xml and find this: `<extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/>` and remove it.

Comment: Yes. I tried removing it, but next i got error for `org.jboss.as.configadmin` and then `org.jboss.as.jaxr` . Should i remove these as well ?

Comment: I dont know the meaning of removing the entry, but kept on removing what all it complained about, and eventually JBoss 7.2 (not wildfly) has started. I have the following error though currently.

jboss.ws.config is missing [jboss.undertow, jboss.web.common.server]